# Can you update environment file variables from webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, webpack-5

I'm seeing a lot of information on *accessing* environment variables within Webpack build systems.

[environment plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)

But what about getting info during each build and **updating** the environment file with that info?
Is this possible and how would you approach it?

Comment: You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or even better the [dotenv-webpack library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)
The `.env` file generates and you use these variables dynamically in your project.

Comment: Yes I've read all of those. Would you mind creating an answer to demonstrate how to update an environment variable from a `webpack.config.js` for use across an application?

Comment: But you have it exactly described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack#user-content-usage)
You just need to generate the .env file then you will need it.